# Checking for a condition within a timeframe period in a dataframe. [Python] [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

So I have a data frame, and I'm trying to check whether:

If a perpetrator and victim are in relation at a certain time (time stamp), whether the reverse happens, and the victim becomes a perpetrator, and vice versa, within a certain time frame.

E.g. `if X attacks Y at time Z` then add a count if `Y` attacks `X` within a time frame (`Z + 24hrs`)

```
        X       Perpetrator          Victim           Time Stamp
44      3              FvdP           Jmallios 2002-11-13 21:53:17   
45      2              FvdP               FvdP 2002-11-13 21:58:59   
46     28               Lir                Lir 2002-11-19 00:47:05   
47     16   194.117.133.118            Tinulim 2002-11-27 00:13:40   
48     15           Tinulim    194.117.133.118 2002-11-27 00:16:03   
49     14             Zocky            Tinulim 2002-11-27 00:23:28   
50     13   194.117.133.118              Zocky 2002-11-27 00:25:31
```

Here is a section of the data frame. An example is when user `194.117.133.118` attacks user `Tinulim`, who then attacks 3 minutes later `194.117.133.118` back. [The timestamp entries are objects in the form `datetime.Timestamp`]

I would like to add both users and a count to a new dataframe. e.g.

```
         Initiator          Retort           Time Stamp
1  194.117.133.118         Tinulim  2002-11-27 00:13:40
```

I am currently using a for loop with iterrows but cannot format it correctly using this function:

```
def time_window_24(time1,time2):
    "Is time2 within 24 hours ahead of time1?"
    if (time2 - time1).days == 0 and time1!=time2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide expected output for the sample input you gave,

Comment: @jo9k Expected output from the example dataframe is given, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to work using `pd.merge_asof` which you can see the API here: [merge_asof docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
data = """
perpetrator,victim,date
FvdP,Jmallios,2002-11-13 21:53:17
FvdP,FvdP,2002-11-13 21:58:59 
Lir,Lir,2002-11-19 00:47:05 
194.117.133.118,Tinulim,2002-11-27 00:13:40 
Tinulim,194.117.133.118,2002-11-27 00:16:03 
Zocky,Tinulim,2002-11-27 00:23:28 
194.117.133.118,Zocky,2002-11-27 00:25:31 
"""
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=[2])
df = df.query('perpetrator != victim')
merged = pd.merge_asof(df,
                       df,
                       on=['date'],
                       right_by=['perpetrator', 'victim'],
                       left_by=['victim', 'perpetrator'],
                       direction='forward',
                       tolerance=pd.tslib.Timedelta('1 day'),
                       suffixes=('', '_res'))
merged = merged.rename(columns={'victim_res': 'initiator',
                                'perpetrator_res': 'retort'})
print(merged[merged.retort.notnull()][['initiator', 'retort', 'date']].to_string())
```

`initiator   retort                date
1  194.117.133.118  Tinulim 2002-11-27 00:13:40`

Comment: Perfect, never heard of merge_asof before so will take a look. Thanks!